# firefox restarting problem in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, updates

i'm using **ubuntu 8.10** . now i updated firefox it doesn't result any error. when i open it the ***back,refresh*** buttons are not working and always shows "**Your browser has been updated and needs to be restarted"**. Can anyone know the problem . if i need to reinstall what commands to execute because im beginner to ubuntu.

Comment: ubuntu 8.10 is out of date,download the latest version of ubuntu

Comment: Did you update the browser using the package management system?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure Firefox is closed. ALT+F2: killall -9 firefox. After that, try it again. If its not working, move your .mozilla folder. (And export your settings, etc.) >> IN a terminal: mv ~/.mozilla ~/.mozilla.old (Later, you can try copying back some necessary stuff of yours. OR you can try Weave extension.) 
Phobia: It happens when only 8.10 works, or 9.04, etc. Someone just cant change. Thats how is it goes on linux.